# Back-transformation in pairs function (lmer analysis)

Tags: r

I'm running lme4 and Im working with a dataset where the variables a,d,e are logtransformed. I wonder how to handle back-transformation concerning the "pairs" function. How do I get the contrast? it is set as a function because in reality there are many columns which I will loop over.

Also, if I logtransform the dataset before I run it in the lmer model, can I tell that the data was logtransformed, even if its not in the model as log(df[,i])?
Many thanks!

```
a <- runif(21)
d <- runif(21)
e <- runif(21)
trt <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],7)
id <- rep(1:7, each=3)
df <- data.frame(id,trt,a,d,e)

func <- function(i){
  dflmer <- lmer(formula= log(df[,i]) ~trt+(1|id), data=df)
  emm <- emmeans(dflmer,"trt")
  emm_df <- data.frame(emm)# I could get the data back-transformed like this
  exp(emm[,c(2,5,6)])
  emm_pairs<- pairs(emm, adjust="fdr") # but how about the pairs function?
  contrast(regrid(e, type="log")) #?
}
```

func(3) # example